# How to check if the class instantiated correctly

Tags: ruby, oop, testing

Say I have a class:

```
class Product
  def initialize(v)
    @var = v
  end
end
```

and I would like to test with RSpec whether the instantiation of the class went alright. Should it be tested within the class or Unit Testing, and how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If your initializer is that simple, it's not worth it to test it.
On the other hand, if you're adding some parameter checking or other logic in your initializer, it might be a good idea to test it out.

Most of the time, the good practice in that case is to raise an IllegalArgumentError if the parameter is wrong. In this case, you can just make sure that initializing the object did (or did not) raise an Error.

If you're doing more convoluted stuff, you might want to check the value of the instance variables. I don't think using `attr_reader` is a good idea for this, as I think changing a class implementation for testing purposes is a bad idea. Instead, I would use `#instance_variable_get` to read the variable.

```
class Foo
  def initialize(mandatory_param, optional_param = nil)
    raise IllegalArgumentError.new("param cannot be #{param}") if mandatory_param == 42
    @var1 = mandatory_param
    @var2 = optional_param unless param.is_a? String
  end
end

describe Foo do
  it "should not accept 42 as an argument" do
    expect { Foo.new(42, 'hello') }.to raise_error(IllegalArgumentError)
  end

  it "should set var2 properly if it's not a String" do
    f = Foo.new('hello', 1)
    f.instance_variable_get(:@var2).should eq 1
  end

  it "should not set var2 if it's a String" do
    f = Foo.new('hello', 'world')
    f.instance_variable_get(:@var2).should be_nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an attr_reader to the class in order to verify its state via RSpec, Test::Unit, Minitest, or anything else. However, what you're talking about is testing basically that Ruby as a language is working, which really isn't something you need to be concerned about.